# How to check if value unique for a certain period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a Ratings model with a phone_id attribute. Before creating a new ratings object I want to check if the phone_id is unique for the past week.

In my model I want to do something like this in the before_save callback:

```
self.all(:conditions => {:created_at => (1.week.ago..Date.today)}).include? self.phone_id
```

Comment: So you're using Rails 2? What version exactly?

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2.12

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in clean sql (performance)

```
select count(phone_id) from ratings where created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord validations with a constraint.

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :phone_id, conditions: -> { where(:created_at => (1.week.ago..Date.today)) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use validation on create:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :unique_phone_within_last_week?, on: :create

private
  def unique_phone_within_last_week?
    self.class.where("created_at > ?", 1.week.ago.to_date)
      .where(phone_id: phone_id).empty? ||
    errors.add(:phone_id, 'is not unique within last week') && false
  end
end
```

#### In Rails 4 you can use validates_uniqueness_of with conditions proc:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :phone_id,
    conditions: -> { where('created_at > ?', 1.week.ago.to_date) }
end
```

Read more about [validates_uniqueness_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of).

#### Checking SQL will be optimal:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "ratings"
WHERE "ratings"."phone_id" = 2 AND ("created_at" > '2014-01-14');
```

#### Note also that

Using interval `1.week.ago..Date.today` is seems to be bad idea,
because records that were created today (in day of checking) are out of scope.

`'2014-01-21 09:10:21' BETWEEN '2014-01-14 11:23:30' AND '2014-01-21'` is false